# Determining specific type to use inside "if constexpr"

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

I am trying to get a feel for using "if constexpr( expr )" and perform actions if a particular type is detected.

I am tinkering with the following bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct aT {};
struct bT {};
struct cT {};

constexpr aT atype;
constexpr bT btype;
constexpr cT ctype;

int main()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(atype), aT>::value)
        std::cout << "I am type " << typeid(atype).name() << std::endl;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(btype), bT>::value)
        std::cout << "I am type " << typeid(btype).name() << std::endl;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(ctype), cT>::value)
        std::cout << "I am type " << typeid(ctype).name() << std::endl;
}
```

I get no compile errors/warnings. However, on execution, none of the if constexpr tests evaluate to true.

If anyone might shine a bit of light on this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is that `if constexpr` really outside of any function? Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constexpr` implies `const` in the context of variable declaration. Try this:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(atype), const aT>::value)
        std::cout << "I am type " << typeid(atype).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or, you can use [`std::remove_const`/`std::remove_cv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv), eg: `std::is_same<std::remove_cv<decltype(atype)>, aT>::value`. There is also [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) in C++20.

Comment: Thanks @cigien!  All I can say on my behalf ... DOH!